# strange methods showing in First Responder received actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am curious about something that I am seeing in interface builder when I right click on the "First Responder" placemark. My question is when I right click the "First Responder" lists its received actions, amongst theses are 5 methods that are defined in one of my early classes, does anyone know why they are showing up, does it matter, is this normal?

## EDIT:

If I right click on [First Responder] on *any* of the nib/xib files in my project (there are 4) I see the following.

[image]

I am just curious why the buttonPressed_XXX methods display in that list (for all the xibs in the project).

Comment: What do you mean by "early classes"?

Comment: Does the edit make it any clearer?

Answer (score 1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBMsk.png

First reponder is action of Keyboard to go off after you finish typing.. in above image all these actions uses keyboard so it shows that page when you remove the action(IBAction) thats it...

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the references from IB? XCode doesn't automatically delete the IBOutlets or IBActions if you hook up objects and get rid of the objects or IBActions. Press x beside the name of the object and the object type to get rid of the IBAction or Outlet. A picture could be helpful.

Comment: These IBActions are used in one of my NIB files, I am just curious why they show up on the First Responder of my other XIB files too.

Comment: because its a first responder method. The first responder is essentially the object that responds. For example, if a keyboard come out when you tap a textview, it is now the first responder. Since the first responder could be ANYTHING, all methods show up. If you want to hook up IBAction, hook it up to the files owner. Thats the standard